# need help in forloop and pandas code optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code and i need to optimize it in better way. I did my best but still i think it can be optimized more.

Am using few date functions and getting the required data. In below code, where can i optimize more for more good performance.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime
import numpy as np
import calendar
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

start_date= date.today()+timedelta(-1461)
end_date=date.today()+timedelta(+1461)
dt= pd.Series(pd.date_range(start=start_date,end=end_date))
da= pd.to_datetime(dt)
iso_year=[]
iso_week=[]
iso_day=[]
dates=[]
mnth=[]
yr=[]
day_of_cal=[]
day_of_cal_name=[]
initial_fir_mon=[]
Last_sun=[]
Cal_week=[]

for date in da:
   dates.append(date)
   yr.append(date.year)
   mnth.append(date.month)
   day_of_cal.append(date.weekday())
   day_of_cal_name.append(calendar.day_name[date.weekday()])
   iso_year.append(date.isocalendar()[0])
   iso_week.append(date.isocalendar()[1])
   iso_day.append(date.isocalendar()[2])
   sel_date=date.strftime('%Y-%m')
   initial_fir_mon.append(np.busday_offset(sel_date,0,roll='forward', weekmask='Mon'))
   my_date=date+relativedelta(months=+1)
   sel_date_1=my_date.strftime('%Y-%m')
   Last_sun.append(np.busday_offset(sel_date_1,-1,roll='following',weekmask='Sun'))
   Cal_week.append(date.strftime('%U'))

df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':dates,
                 'year':yr,
                 'Month':mnth,
                 'iso_year':iso_year,
                 'iso_week':iso_week,
                 'iso_day':iso_day,
                 'day_of_cal': day_of_cal,
                 'day_of_cal_name':day_of_cal_name,
                 'initial_fir_mon':initial_fir_mon,
                 'Last_sun':Last_sun,
                 'Cal_week':Cal_week
                })
df["day_of_cal"]=np.where(df["day_of_cal"]==0,2,
                            np.where(df["day_of_cal"]==1,3,
                                     np.where(df["day_of_cal"]==2,4,
                                              np.where(df["day_of_cal"]==3,5,
                                                       np.where(df["day_of_cal"]==4,6,
                                                               np.where(df["day_of_cal"]==5,7,1))))))
df["Fisc_yr_wk"]= df["iso_year"].astype(str) + df["iso_week"].astype(str)
df["iso_day_name"]=np.where(df["iso_day"]==1,'Monday',
                            np.where(df["iso_day"]==2,'Tuesday',
                                     np.where(df["iso_day"]==3,'Wednesday',
                                              np.where(df["iso_day"]==4,'Thursday',
                                                       np.where(df["iso_day"]==5,'Friday',
                                                               np.where(df["iso_day"]==6,'Saturday','Sunday'))))))
```

Let me know where can i optimize and suggest me to make it more optimized code

Answer (score 0):

The nested `np.where()` functionality is unnecessarily complex.

The day_of_cal element of the dataframe can be handled (in the main loop) like this:

```
day_of_cal.append([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1][date.weekday()])
```

...thereby eliminating the need for its modification immediately after dataframe construction.

You can do a similar thing for iso_day_name. In this case you'll need an additional empty array, then in the main loop:

```
iso_day_name.append([None, 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday',
                         'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][date.isocalendar()[2]])
```

...then make the appropriate addition to the dataframe construction code.

In this way you can eliminate both of the nested `np.where()` statements.

On my machine, this change gives a slight overall improvement and a total run time of 110ms

Comment: Thank you @Andy,  Can you please add change in my snippet so that i may understand better please.. am new bie

Comment: iso_day_name is not working.. its coming as none

Answer (score 0):

Constructing the data frame can be done easier with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Date"] = pd.date_range("2017-07-24", "2025-07-22")
df["Year"] = df["Date"].dt.year
df["Month"] = df["Date"].dt.month
df["Week"] = df["Date"].dt.isocalendar().week
df["Weekday"] = df["Date"].dt.weekday
....
```